# Which browser has the best support for HTML 5 currently?

Tags: html

Where can I test HTML 5 functionality today - is there any test build of any rendering engines which would allow testing, or is it to early? I'm aware that much of the spec hasn't been finalised, but some has, and it would be good to try it out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ones that are built using a recent webkit build, and Presto.

Safari 3.1 for webkit
Opera for Presto.

I'm pretty sure firefox will start supporting html5 partially in 3.1

All support is extremely partial. Check [here for information on what is supported.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML_5))

Comment: Is this still the case? which has more support now, safari 4 or ff 3.6?

Comment: Firefox Rock ans still in the run, of course
http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Getting_a_WebGL_Implementation
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/
:)

Answer (score 15):

To test **your** browser, go to http://html5test.com/. The code is being maintained at: github dot com slash NielsLeenheer slash html5test.

Comment: This site is exceptional.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 9):

http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Implementations_in_Web_browsers has information maintained by the WHATWG community (and everyone who drops by and edits it).

Disclaimer: I'm a member of that community.

Answer (score 4):

Major browsers are providing increased support now.

http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/05/google-bets-big-on-html-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems that new browsers support most of the tags: `<header>`, `<section>` etc. For older browsers (IE, Fx2, Camino etc) then you can use this to allow styling of these tags:

```
document.createElement('header');
```

Would make these older browsers allow CSS styling of a header tag, instead of just ignoring it.

This means that you can now use the new tags without any loss of functionality, which is a good start!

Comment: Does that actually help in Firefox 2 or old Camino?

Answer (score 0):

Opera also has some support.

Generally however, it is too early to test out. You'll probably have to wait a year or 2 before any browser will have enough realistic support to test against.

**EDIT**
Wikipedia has a good article on [how much of HTML 5 various layout engines have implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML_5)). It includes specific aspects of HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

i think right now is Firefox 3.6.2, but when internet explorer 9 launched, it will support HTML5

Answer (score 0):

This page is a neat summary, but is not entirely accurate:

http://findmebyip.com/litmus#target-selector