# Which web browsers support the HTML5 <device> tag?

Tags: html

I read some time ago about the possibility to use media stream from a USB or rs232 device with the `<device>` tag such as a webcam with HTML5.

Is there a web browser that supports this right now? (i.e. nighty builds of Chrome, Webkit...)

Comment: possible duplication of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150577/which-browser-has-the-best-support-for-html-5-currently

Comment: In principle, <device> isn't part of HTML5 but part of the post-HTML5 "next generation additions still in development".

Comment: `<device>` got deprecated, even before first prototypes appeared. use `getUserMedia` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now we have released our modified WebKit library so that you can test these features yourself. Note that the "device" element is no longer available in the WhatWG spec, it has been replaced  with a JavaScript API (navigator.getUserMedia(...)).

You can read more at: https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-experiment-real-time-communication-browser

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no browsers support the device APIs yet. The specification seems to be in a rather early stage and can be found here - http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-device/

Ericsson Labs did a [blog post](https://labs.ericsson.com/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers) with some snippets of code which is great, but there's no playground to try these out.

Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration) was asked on SO last year, but looks like things haven't changed much since.

However, you might find this interesting - nothing production worthy but still fun. This [blog post](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2009/11/17/using-a-webcam-with-html-5-via-vlc/) talks about using the `<video>` tag to stream from a webcam via VLC.

Comment: Unfortunately the latest update from Ericsson is that the <device> tag has been removed from the HTML5 spec.  https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-implementing-device-and-stream-management-webkit

Answer (score 2):

There's also an experimental build of Opera Mobile for Android that supports navigator.getUserMedia().

http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2011/03/23/webcam-orientation-preview

Comment: It's not experimental anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

As @stefan-lund already mentioned the device tag has been replaced by the WebRTC specification.

Opera has a dev build available at http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/labs-more-fun-using-the-web-with-getusermedia-and-native-pages/ which supports WebRTC.

Chrome should get support in early 2012 (http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/24/chrome-getting-native-gamepad-webcam-and-webrtc-support-in-early-2012/)

If you just want to receive a video upload you can also use the Media Capture API instead, which is  a special type of the `input type=file` element.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
```

Browser support for that is covered here: [The Media Capture API - any existing implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825405/the-media-capture-api-any-existing-implementations)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome just added support for this today (dev channel Chrome) >>
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/LuY7zYLA8sA