# The Media Capture API - any existing implementations?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

I have been reading up on the draft [Device APIs](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/) and am wondering whether there are any implementations of the [Media Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/).

Ericsson seem to have [some](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk) [demos](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-implementing-device-and-stream-management-webkit) up, however haven't released the source. There's also a bug report on [Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55377).

I don't mind whether implementation takes the form of a:

- nightly build
- patch
- branch
- browser extension
- backfill JavaScript

...so long as it allows experimenting against the interface as is thus far suggested in the standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html) implements the HTML Media Capture specification (a draft version).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I'll try to get it working in the emulator, in which case this would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @stoive did you manage to get the media capture api working with android?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft recently (June 2011) announced that they have released a prototype for IE 9 that implements the audio portion of the HTML Media Capture spec.  You can read the announcement and download the prototype for experimentation from here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2011/06/07/new-media-capture-audio-prototype-released.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A WebRTC committer wrote that the «device element has gone the way of dodo»:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55377#c10

So a better alternative seems to be the WhatWG getUserMedia:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html

and specifically

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html#obtaining-local-multimedia-content

Answer (score 3):

The Media Capture API is no longer being worked on — it was split into two specifications: [Media Capture and Streams](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/) (aka getUserMedia) and [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/). Support, as of May 2013, is:

**getUserMedia**

- Opera (desktop & mobile)
- Firefox (desktop)
- Chrome (desktop)

Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

**HTML Media Capture**

- Android 3.0
- iOS 6
- BlackBerry 10
- Mobile Firefox 10.0
- Chrome for Android 0.16

Source: lots of searching and testing