# can client side web technolgy be used to scan an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am working on a website. Users need to scan documents often. Right now they use some system application to scan and save images in a directory and later upload them. I am supposed to make process more cohesive. I am working with django, python and jquery. How to use scanner and scan an image at client side?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901584/is-it-possible-to-have-flash-access-a-generic-twain-scanner and here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+scanner+from+browser

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible with [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/), but is currently [experimental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825405/the-media-capture-api-any-existing-implementations) [at best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)#Related_specifications).