# how to capture image using webcam in jquery-spring

Tags: jquery, spring

I want to capture image using webcam with jquery.

I have a jsp page named patienRegistration. How can I implement this feature in spring framework?

please give me full description with example i am new to this.

I have seen http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ this website but I don't know 
how to implement this in my project means i don't know where to write and what to write.

plz plz plz help me soon...thnx...

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [with difficulty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074230/how-to-access-webcam-from-html5), as it depends on browser support [which is not widely supported right now](http://caniuse.com/stream).

The latter-day alternative is to use Flash to work with the user's webcam locally; to interpet the Flash camera data on the server you need a dedicated Flash communications/media server. I'm not an expert here so I cannot make any recommendations.

JSP/Spring is inappropriate because they are built around a request/response design, whereas streaming media is a different paradigm.

EDIT: I just realised that you're looking to get a single image. The same client-side restrictions apply, but I understand that you can coax Flash Player into uploading still frames from a webcam, however I don't know how you do this exactly.