# how to correct zmq address in use error with django

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to create a simple video streaming site with Django. I am using cv2 for starting the webcam and ZMQ for transferring data from client to server. I found this **[link](https://github.com/CT83/SmoothStream/)** with which I wrote the networking part of the code.

The code by itself works fine, but when I create a simple HTML file to start the live stream through the browser the code fails with this error message

```
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address in use
```

I guess this error arises because the IP Django uses and the IP ZMQ tries to uses is the same. But I am not sure how to rectify this error.

This is my code so far

#### server.py

```
def start_server():
    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    print('socket created')

    footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
    footage_socket.bind('tcp://192.168.1.18:5020')

    print('binding complete')
    print('server ready')

    return footage_socket

def recv_content(socket, face_cascade_path):

    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(face_cascade_path)

    while True:
        try:
            data = socket.recv_string()
            img = base64.b64decode(data)
            npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
            frame = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
            print(frame)

            face = cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3)

            for (x, y, w, h) in face:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            cv2.imshow("Stream", frame)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

#### views.py

```
from server import *

def index(request):

    face_cascade_path = '../../../TRAINED MODELS/FACE/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
    footage_socket = start_server()
    recv_content(footage_socket, face_cascade_path)

    return render(request, 'index.html')

def start_client(request):
    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    footage_socket.connect('tcp://192.168.1.18:5020')

    print('connected to server')
    print('starting video on client machine')

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

    while True:
        try:
            grabbed, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
            footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            camera.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <h2>CAMERA SERVER CLIENT TEST</h2>

    <p>
    Click the start_client button to start camera. Each frame of the stream is sent to the server.
    </p>
    <p>
      The camera code is running on the client side.
    </p>

    <a href ='start_client/'><button>start client</button></a>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Thank you in advance

#### EDIT 1 - I have edited to add the client part of the code and index.html as well. The start_client function is under views.py. This function is run when the start_client button in index.html is clicked

#### EDIT 2 - I have edited the question to add a screenshot of my problem. While I dont face the "address in use" error when I refresh the page after adding the try-except block, the webpage is still not loading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should adopt another port instead of the common `8000` port which usually is in use.

Another idea is that any socket options must be placed before `bind` or `connect` method in ZMQ.

So your code will look something like this:

```
def start_server():
    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

    try:
        footage_socket.bind('tcp://192.168.1.18:5020')  # Another port used.
    except:
        pass

    return footage_socket
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Do not forget to change the port on the client side (`.connect()`) to `5020`.

---

[UPDATE]:

- I updated the answer with a simple `try-except` for the refreshing problem.
  Or you can use the `footage_socket.close()` method to clear the previous socket or you can put on a condition which checks the previous socket.
- [How to take a snapshot with client-side camera in my Django web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659698/how-to-take-image-snapshot-with-client-side-camera-in-my-django-web-application)

Comment: Hey! I tried changing the port to the server and the client. Now when I start the django server and navigate to the ip address the page just keeps loading. and nothing happens. If I try reloading the page, I get address in use error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The django server runs in 192.168.1.18:8000, zmq server runs in 192.168.1.18:5020 and I changed the port in client accordingly as well

Comment: @Sashaank Can you put on client code with an edit in your question? Did you change the socket option placement (before binding the IP)?

Comment: I have just added the client part of the code. I changed the socket option placement in server.py. I have added that code as well

Comment: At first I thought, because of the while loop under **recv_content()** function in **server.py** the code was not going to the next line in **views.py**. So I removed the while loop and started the django server again. I am still facing the same issue. The page never loads. if I try refreshing, I encounter address in use error. Please help me

Comment: Hi. I have edited to question and added a screenshot of my error. I added the try-except block and am no longer facing the address in use error. But the webpage still does not load. Is this because of the while loop in server.py? how do I rectify this?

Comment: Hi. Just figured out that there is no problem in the server.py file. the recv_content() function in server.py gets executed when i navigate to the IP address. Then when I start client.py in a separate command prompt, the camera feed is executed.

Comment: I wanted the website to open where I would press a button named start_client and when the button is pressed the camera feed is started.

Comment: I just changed the code to add a start_server button in index.html. Now the code works fine. But the when start_client button is pressed from the client machine, only the camera on the server side is activated. How do I rectify that?

Comment: @Sashaank I haven't any experienced todo that.

Comment: @Sashaank I think your problem is that, both view.py(zmq.PUB) and server.py(zmq.SUB) placed in your server, so you can't get the client camera with this method.

Comment: @Sashaank Might be you need to JS language to overcome that, I suggest open another post(question) with this content: `How to get camera data from the client side to server side using Django?`

Comment: @Sashaank There is no bother. If this post helped you, a +1 would be appreciated.