# Which browsers on pc have supported html5 so far?

Tags: html, html5-video

I know that most browsers already support HTML5 on handphones, but what's the status with PC browsers, especially for HTML5 `<video>`?

What are good websites and resources for keeping up with how well different browsers support HTML5?

Comment: See [Which browser has the best support for HTML 5 currently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150577/which-browser-has-the-best-support-for-html-5-currently)

Comment: @Matthew One might argue that that question is two years old, things probably changed a bit in the meantime.

Comment: @Matthew - Are you insane? That question is from 2008. Even answers from 2 months ago would be outdated now.

Comment: Yeah, a question like this gets old, FAST. Maybe a "what websites maintain the best current information about HTML5 support?"

Comment: @artlung, a question like listing prominent websites is more likely to stand the test of time. Those websites themselves may get outdated or superseded with time, but that's not happening with a nightly build of browser X.

Comment: @Anurag - it really is a good question. Who *does* provide good info about this stuff? Obviously the browser vendors provide support information, but it's not in their interest to keep up with all the other browsers.

Comment: @artlung - I fully agree with you on having a generic question for listing prominent links rather than listing the progress level here itself in the form of answers. Also, keeping tabs on where the other browsers stand in terms of implementation may be something that browser vendors watch out for as to not lag behind too much, but they wouldn't necessarily maintain something like this for the eyes of the public. Although MDC does list out other browser's inconsistencies in certain APIs which is very helpful in making MDC the one-stop-shop for my JavaScript documentation needs.

Answer (score 6):

This "infographic" sums it up pretty well:

[http://media.focus.com/images/uploaded/fyi/wtf-html5-infographic/HTML5__.jpg](http://www.focus.com/images/view/11905/)

Answer (score 2):

- [Comparison of layout engines
  (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29) (Wikipedia)
- [HTML5 Implementations in Web browsers](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Implementations_in_Web_browsers) ([WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/))
- [Compatibility tables on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Browser status for HTML5 and CSS3 implementation.

- http://html5readiness.com/

A presentation written in HTML5 with live examples for manual testing.

- http://apirocks.com/html5/html5.html

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is the browser that best support HTML5... in second turn is FIREFOX, after that is safari, then opera... and after opera many ones...

The one you must know that isnt supporting HTML5 in anyway (the true, only 10%) is Internet Explorer.

Try this site to test thi HTML5 support for browsers..

http://html5test.coms/

Answer (score 0):

This page has a nice explanation of different features and which browser, older, current or planned will support it.

http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5&statuses=rec,pr,cr,wd,ietf